# id the HW port and protocol

Tags: hardware, serial-communication

i have a vtech baby monitor and since i want to be aware of it while i'm playing in VR (PC, HTC vaive/Valve index) i still want to see if the baby starts crying.

on this monitor there is external access to a 6 pin connector. opening the unit i see the pins are labeled:
SF_CSB,
SF_MISO,
VDD3,
TX,
RX,
GND.

The VDD,TX,RX,GND i think its a UART port, i need help identifying the other 2 pins. i found them on some LG TV's manuals but without explanation.

anybody is familiure with this port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems CSB is [Chip select](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/453360/why-ss-and-miso-of-sensor-is-permanently-high), and MISO (Master in/Slave out) is a typical name for an SPI pin.

Comment: but SPI has more pins, like clock and MOSI.
is this a weird combination of the 2?

Comment: Having both MOSI and MISO is only needed for bidirectional communication, it can be missing if you only need to send stuff. But missing clock is indeed weird. Possibly you're supposed to use a clock signal from somewhere else, not sure.